# posting url with string parameter that contains LINE BREAKS using java

Tags: java

i want to sent SMS from my JAVA APPLICATION in the following format:
NAME: Customer Name
ConfNO: 1234
Date: 2012-05-15
NoOfPax: Seven
Since i am using external sms gateway i need to post it as URL from the application. When i recive the SMS i dont see line breaks instead the text display \n. Please help.My Code is

```
String senderid = "SMSALERT";
    String to = "97112345678";
    String text = "Reservation INFO\nName:Customer Name\nConfNO: KN1234\nTime: 12:00PM\n#Pax:5\nThank You for Choosing US";
    String type = "text";
    String ppgHost = "www.yahoo.com";
    String username = "username";
    String password = "password";
    String datetime = "2012-05-15 12:00:00";
    String path = "index.php";
    try {
        HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        List<NameValuePair> qparams = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
        qparams.add(new BasicNameValuePair("username", username));
        qparams.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password", password));
        qparams.add(new BasicNameValuePair("senderid", senderid));
        qparams.add(new BasicNameValuePair("to", to));
        qparams.add(new BasicNameValuePair("text", text));
        qparams.add(new BasicNameValuePair("type", type));
        qparams.add(new BasicNameValuePair("datetime", datetime));
        URI uri = URIUtils.createURI("http", ppgHost, -1, path, URLEncodedUtils.format(qparams, "UTF-8"), null);
        HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(uri);
        System.out.println(httppost.getURI());
        HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httppost);
        System.out.println(response.getStatusLine());
```

Comment: You should be URL-encoding all of the query params.

Comment: Yes, I have encoded the entire arrayList as in    URLEncodedUtils.format(qparams, "UTF-8"),

Comment: How does the code of URLEncodedUtils look like? I think your are doing the encoding wrong.

Comment: i thought the entire arraylist willbe encoded using URLENCODEDUTILS. i will try encoding all the parameter using URLencoder. IS there any other way..

Comment: Can anyone provide a sample code.

Comment: i tried with <br> as well. but it doesnt seem to work. i am providing the type as text does it need to be changed to anyother format for example unicode

Answer (score 35, accepted):

If it's a URL you can use the percent-encoded value for a new line, it's `%0D%0A` although `%0A` (ASCII 10 - line feed) or `%0D` (ASCII 13 - carriage return) should work alone.

Comment: i tried %0A but its still not displaying the LINE BREAk. THanks again.

Comment: i appended using %0D%0A then i get int he sms as \r\n

Comment: Thanks kirchartz. It worked like this -    URLEncoder.encode(LINE1)+ '%0A' + URLEncoder.encode(LINE2)

Answer (score 0):

All the parameters needs to be URL encoded. Further, it is a good practice to user system line separator rather than hardcoding "\n"

`System.getProperty("line.separator");`

Comment: Can i give in this way ---> String encodedString = URLEncoder.encode(text, "UTF-8");                                       encodedString = encodedString.replaceAll(System.getProperty("line.separator"), "\n");

Comment: \n and line.separator works when i try to insert the text from the url into MYSQL table. But when on the SMS its a problem.

Comment: when i replace \n with System.getproperty("line.separator") the sms is displayed as \n

Comment: You can try sending the standard carriage return ("\r") and line feed character ("\n") [line.separator] instead of just "/n". Further, if you can, probably browse through the external sms gateway API docs on how they read a newline character, It may vary from standards. Check the below mentioned link for more insight [here](http://www.nowsms.com/discus/messages/12/3732.html).